# Heroku deployment of Django app unsuccessful

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku but I get this strange error when i run the following command.

Any idea why this happens? I've googled it but I found nothing that would help.

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/djangos/jobs# git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Thanks in advance for any hints/help!

Comment: have you registered your ssh key to Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,you should login.

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: adam@example.com
Password: 
Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn] 
Generating new SSH public key.
Uploading ssh public key /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Also, if you login, you should try "**git pull heroku master**" then try to "**git push heroku master**".

[Getting Started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart)

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem , Add your ssh key to heroku by `$ heroku keys:add` .
check out my blogpost http://www.codesucksmybrain.blogspot.com/2012/04/deploy-django-app-on-heroku-platform.html

Answer (score 1):

verify that the name of the SSH-KEY is "id_rsa" and that the secret key is the one you believe in this file, if it is safe to re-create the key and leave it with that name "id_rsa"